# Нужны ли запятые в предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Есть два предложения. Если во втором я ещё более-менее уверен, что запятая нужна, то вот относительно первого — наоборот. В первом предложении, в части, которая после "что" и до "он решил", отсутствует сказуемое и есть только подлежащее, отчего я и смутился: можно ли считать фрагмент "что полулюди довольно узконаправленны" простым предложением или оно объединяется с последующим?

1. Припомнив ему, что полулюди довольно узконаправленны(,) он решил более не научать его своим жизненным опытом
2. И не забавно ли, что люди не знают(,) кто они.

Answer (score 2):

***Припомнив ему, что полулюди довольно узконаправленны, он решил более не научать его своим жизненным опытом.***
Предложение сложноподчинённое. Первая грамматическая основа - **он решил не научать**, вторая - **полулюди узконаправленны** (составное именное сказуемое с отсутствующей связкой *есть*). Придаточное находится внутри главного. **Знаки поставлены верно**.

***И не забавно ли, что люди не знают, кто они.***
Сложноподчинённое предложение с двумя придаточными, соединёнными последовательно. 1 предложение - безличное  *И не забавно ли*..., второе - *...что люди не знают*, третье - ***...кто они***. Третье предложение присоединяется союзным словом - местоимением ***кто***, которое выполняет функцию сказуемого. ***Они*** - подлежащее. **Знаки поставлены верно**.

Comment: «Первая грамматическая основа - он решил не научать, вторая - полулюди узконаправленны (составное именное сказуемое с отсутствующей связкой есть)» — а куда девалось «припомнив ему»?

Comment: Вы действительно кое-что именно «упустили», а не сознательно обошли молчанием или что-то в этом роде: в первом предложении грамматическая основа ОДНА, и это — «он решил».

Comment: @ЕгорСальков Егор, в первом предложении основа таки "он решил не научать". https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/sostavnoe-glagolnoe-skazuemoe-primeryi.html В качестве связки могут выступать

а) глаголы со значением желания, волеизъявления

ПРИМЕРЫ:
хотеть, желать, стремиться, стараться, решить, мечтать, любить, браться, пытаться, пробовать, согласиться, намереваться
хотел научиться;
стремился уехать;
решил остаться.  Основа в главном предложении действительно одна. Кто спорит? А в придаточном вторая - "полулюди узконаправленны").

Comment: Все эти глаголы действительно могут выступать в качестве связки, но в данном случае инфинитив «не научать» выступает в функции дополнения: решил (что?) не научать. Не огорчайтесь: правильно определять синтаксическую роль инфинитива в предложении — это проблема многих!

Comment: «Именно синтаксическая роль инфинитива в предложении — главная сложность в работе с этой глагольной формой. Он может выполнять роль подлежащего, входить в состав сказуемого, быть дополнением, определением и обстоятельством. Научиться быстро определять роль глагола в неопределенной форме можно только после тщательного разбора предложений, в которых есть инфинитив. Примеры предложений:
(...) Учитель попросил детей не шуметь. Дополнение: попросил (о чем?) не шуметь». http://teacher-portal.ru/morfologiya/infinitiv-v-russkom-yazyke-primery.html

Comment: Ну, это даже школьники хорошо знают). Спасибо за полемику. Подумайте ещё!

Comment: Что именно «хорошо знают школьники»? Что в составном глагольном сказуемом частица «не» может стоять не только перед связочной частью, но и перед инфинитивом? Тогда попросите у них доказательств того, что такое сказуемое является составным глагольным.

Comment: «Основа в главном предложении действительно одна. Кто спорит? А в придаточном вторая» — бросьте, Екатерина: «даже школьники хорошо знают», что всё, зависимое от деепричастия, есть деепричастный оборот, и никакое «придаточное» там даже мимо не пробегало.

Answer (score 0):

В предложении *Припомнив ему, что полулюди довольно узконаправленны(,) он решил более не научать его своим жизненным опытом* «части, которая после "что" и до "он решил"» сказуемое и не положено: это часть не чего-нибудь, а **деепричастного оборота** и находится в зависимости от деепричастия *припомнив*. Так что отмеченная запятая необходима: она закрывает оборот.

Comment: Егор, хочу напомнить Вам, что деепричастный оборот обычно привязан к глаголу, поэтому в Вашем предложении  грамматическая основа главного предложения "он решил не научать", а обстоятельство, выраженное  деепричастным оборотом (припомнив ему), относится к этой грамматической основе. При этом само обстоятельство осложнено придаточным предложением

Comment: Простите, а что значит «обычно привязан»? Следует ли из такой формулировки, что в некоторых случаях он вместе со своим «придаточным предложением» необычно не привязан? И можно посмотреть доказательство, что в составном глагольном сказуемом с инфинитивом (именно в нём!) частица «не» может стоять не перед связочной частью, а перед инфинитивом?

Answer (score 0):

**О некоторых грамматических вопросах в данной теме**

*Припомнив ему, что полулюди довольно узконаправленны, он решил более не научать его своим жизненным опытом.*

**А. О придаточном предложении, которое относится к деепричастию в главном предложении**

Цитатата:  *… всё, зависимое от деепричастия, есть деепричастный оборот, и никакое «придаточное» там даже мимо не пробегало.*

1. В принципе придаточное  предложение может относиться ко всему главному предложению или к опорному слову в главном предложении. Здесь же, как я понимаю, деепричастный оборот **«решил» включить**  придаточное в свой состав? Но насколько это справедливо?

А выглядит это так, будто структура низшего порядка  **хочет подчинить  и включить в себя** структуру более высокого порядка.

В простом предложении, осложненном деепричастным оборотом, один **предикативный** центр, связанный со сказуемым. Деепричастный оборот обозначает добавочное действие и является полупредикативным, то есть это более низкая и подчиненная структура в этой иерархии.

2. Что касается **сложноподчиненного предложения**, то там **два предикативных** центра,  но они неравноправны между собой: предикативный центр придаточного подчинен предикативному центру главного предложения (по смыслу и грамматике), а **показателем подчиненности** является подчинительный союз, включенный в придаточное предложение.
3. А что происходит у нас? **Полупредикативное деепричастие претендует на придаточное предложение с собственным предикативным центром.** Это не по правилам, и это есть нарушение иерархических связей.

Граница в СПП проходит по  подчинительному союзу, а полупредикативное деепричастие остается в пределах главного предложения.

**Б . Еще более непонятен вопрос с частицей НЕ**

1. *Он решил учить/не учить язык.*  Составное глагольное сказуемое, модальная связка.
2. *Он решил  (что?)  учить/не учить дикарей своему жизненному опыту.* Это простое глагольное сказуемое + дополнение.  (Инфинитив обозначает действие, не отнесенное к субъекту действия.)

**Но при чем тут частица НЕ?** Она может стоять или не стоять перед инфинитивом в свободном порядке в обоих случаях.